# Laravel Mail nested components utilizing markdown are not parsed correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

When I'm using `->markdown()` method for send markdown mail in Laravel
and using example used in [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#writing-markdown-messages), I see that instead of a button in my E-Mail I see the plain HTML code.

my template :

```
@component('mail::message')
    # Order Shipped

    Your order has been shipped!

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url])
        View Order
    @endcomponent

    Thanks,<br>
    {{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I got my problem in [git issus](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20791) and Laravel Doc :

> Do not use excess indentation when writing Markdown emails. Markdown parsers will render indented content as code blocks.

But phpstorm reformats my code that cause markdown render my inner components as code snippet.

Comment: Thanks I also spend hour of debugging until found your answer from google

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glade your problem has ben resolved